# Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : Timeout was reached:

Tags: r, curl

I'm trying to download a database and it's giving the following error:

> pnadc.svy = get_pnadc(year = 2017, quarter = 4, vars = c("VD4001",
> "VD4001"), defyear=2017, defperiod=4, labels=TRUE, deflator=TRUE,
> design=TRUE, saveir=tempdir ())
>
> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :   Timed out:
> [ftp.ibge.gov.br] Failed to connect to ftp.ibge.gov.br port 443 after
> 10004 ms: Timed out

I've already tried running some selection options but the same message appears:

> httr::GET("http://cran.r-project.org/Rlogo.jpg") Error in
> curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :   Timeout was reached:
> [cran.r-project.org] Failed to connect to cran.r-project.org port 80
> after 10006 ms: Timeout was reached
>
> GET("http://httpbin.org/delay/1", timeout(99)) Error in
> curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :   Timeout was reached:
> [httpbin.org] Failed to connect to httpbin.org port 80 after 10002 ms:
> Timeout was reached

Can anyone tell me what it could be?

I'm operating R from my workplace.